# A particular app (Visual Studio 2013) has lost write access to particular directories

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, roaming-profiles

I'm a software developer working in a large corporate environment that uses roaming profiles accross the network so my profile directory is stored on a network location: `\\nas\home$\username` and mapped to a local drive letter automatically.

Since a day or two ago, when I try and use Visual Studio 2013 to edit files in particular directories, it can read the file, but can't write (it either prompts to save as a new file elsewhere or displays various errors such as:

`Could not find a part of the path '\\nas\home$\username\mydocuments\...'.`

or

`The system cannot find the path specified`).

or

`.. cannot be created, please ensure this is a writeable path.`

This only occurs when using VS and affected directories match. Changing either one of those and it works fine. I can use VS to save files elsewhere in my profile (including parent directories of affected directories). I can also use other apps like notepad to edit the files in affected directories, and VS will happily read the changes.

The files aren't marked read only and the directories have `Full Control` access to my username. If I copy/paste a parent directory containing an affected directory, VS can now write to the copy/pasted version. It works around one problem but other affected files are config files VS needs that I can't necessarily move about so would like to find a proper solution. Things I have tried:

- Manually setting folders to unset read only
- Rebooting / disconnecting and reconnecting network cable
- Logging on to my profile elsewhere (I can write to the files using Windows or Visual Web Developer Express 2012)

Something that may have caused it: I tried to log in to machine a day or two prior and received a message to say my profile couldn't be loaded and will use a local saved one. I continued as normal making backups of files just in case. I haven't received that message logging in since. However some files affected are ones I didn't use the day I received that message, so not convinced it directly related.

Also possibly related: An affected directory is marked as read only (even when I unset it, it re-appears) even though all the child files are not marked read only. I'm sure i've seen this before though so not convinced it's relevant but including it in case it is.

I decided to put it here rather than SO as I suspect it's a permissions issue rather than Visual Studio itself but if approppriate I can cross-post it there?

To make diagnosing and fixing more frustrating, I don't have admin access to my machine and my ICT department has slow response times so i'll need to minimise the amount of tickets I raise with them. I'm contemplating raising a ticket to re-install VS but could take a while so any other suggestions is gladly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** I have just noticed if I try to create a directory in an affected folder using Explorer, the window hangs and becomes unresponsive. If I create it elsewhere and drag it in, the Moving dialog just says `Calculating` for speed and time remaining indefinitely. So it is definitely a network or disk issue, rather than VS.

**Fixed:** I logged in on another machine, was able to copy a blank folder into an affected folder. Once that happened, all the write issues vanished for that folder on my normal machine. Repeated this with the other affected folders and so far, it keeps working. I don't know what the hell it's doing but it's sorting it.

Answer (score 0):

I logged in on another machine, was able to copy a blank folder into an affected folder. Once that happened, all the write issues vanished for that folder on my normal machine. Repeated this with the other affected folders and so far, it keeps working. I don't know what the hell it's doing but it's sorting it.

I'm starting to think it's a problem with the NAS as one of the errors for Visual Studio has the name "ERROR_FILE_OFFLINE" I haven't made any files offline and you'd think if it was offline you couldn't read or write to it, but there you go. Changing the structure seems to refresh things.